# check if the c# method is used in the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way or plugin to see if a method (get the list of methods) in the project that are not been used?

I can get the list of methods in the project by using this . But how to check if that method is being used in the project

```
Type.GetMethods()
```

Comment: Do you want to include invocation by reflection?

Comment: VS2013 or greater will tell you usage count via CodeLens.  Or you can right-click and hit 'Find Usages' (or 'Find All References', resharper has ruined me).  But these aren't foolproof as a method could be loaded via reflection.

Comment: For explicit references, you can simply right-click the method name and select "Find all references" from the context menu. For reflection, as far as I know a string search across the project/solution is your only option.

Comment: Furthermore, [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will find unused methods and report them (you'll still have the possibility to mark them as *used implicitely*, such as by reflection).

Comment: Thanks you all. I have been using resharper but now i am using just code

Comment: i was thinking instead of  going to each method, i can get the list of methods that are not used. But never mind I will check by find all references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very hard to find in large project. But you can try several approaches.

1. Right click on the function -> find all references. These references could be also death code. So check for references for each. And again after you find out if it is really used or not.
2. Search the method name by text and check the occurrences. Repeat for callee if needed.
3. Another simple approach is put the breakpoint inside and run application and go throw scenarios. You hardly go throw all scenarios. But you can cover part of it.

Sometime it can be tricky if reflection is used. Such method could be called by reflection and you hardly find it out by reference search.

No approach is 100%. You can try any combination of them.